# Android How to send Retrofit2.0 post request with json body containing imagefiles and other attributes

Tags: android, json, image, retrofit, retrofit2

How to send Retrofit2.0 post request with json body containing imagefiles and other attributes
I have an object model which is serialized with keys and also image string to hold image paths as below

```
public class SeekerProfileModel implements Serializable 
{

    @SerializedName("fname")
    private String fname=null;
    @SerializedName("lname")
    private String lname=null;
    @SerializedName("paswd")
    private String password=null;
    @SerializedName("promoter")
    private String promoter=null;
    @SerializedName("dob")
    private String dob=null;
    @SerializedName("gender")
    private String gender=null;
    @SerializedName("ph")
    private String phone=null;
    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email=null;
    @SerializedName("weight")
    private String weight=null;
    @SerializedName("height")
    private String height=null;
    @SerializedName("qualification")
    private String qualification=null;
    @SerializedName("color")
    private String color=null;
    @SerializedName("lang_known")
    private String languages=null;
    @SerializedName("experience")
    private String experience=null;
    @SerializedName("exp_type")
    private String experienceType=null;
    @SerializedName("dres_code")
    private String dressCode=null;
    @SerializedName("vehicle_mode")
    private String vehicleMode=null;
    @SerializedName("id_proof")
    private String idproof=null;
    @SerializedName("size")
    private String size=null;
    @SerializedName("photo1")
    private String photo1=null;
    @SerializedName("photo2")
    private String photo2=null;
    @SerializedName("photo3")
    private String photo3=null;
    @SerializedName("address")
    private String address=null;
    @SerializedName("landmark")
    private String landmark=null;
    @SerializedName("location")
    private String location=null;
    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city=null;
    @SerializedName("state")
    private String state=null;
    @SerializedName("contry")
    private String contry=null;
    @SerializedName("pincode")
    private String pincode=null;
    @SerializedName("bank_name")
    private String bankName=null;
    @SerializedName("ac_name")
    private String accountName=null;
    @SerializedName("ac_number")
    private String accontNumber=null;
    @SerializedName("ifsc")
    private String Ifsc=null;
    @SerializedName("br_name")
    private String branchName=null;
}
```

My Interface as below

```
@Multipart
 @POST("empowerapp/seekerreg.php")
 Call<ResponseModel> registerSeeker(
 @Body SeekerProfileModel profileModel);
```

And My method to call is as below

```
public void registerSeeker(SeekerProfileModel profileModel) {

    System.out.println("###exp" + s_exp.getText().toString());

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Allconstants.MAIN_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitInterface service = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

    Call<ResponseModel> call = service.registerSeeker(profileModel);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ResponseModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            System.out.println("###coming" + response.body().getStatus());
            pd.dismiss();
            if (response.body().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
            {
                pd.dismiss();
                loginSession.createLoginSession(Allconstants.SEEKER,Allconstants.S_REG_ACTIVITY,response.body().getName(), response.body().getId());
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("###coming"+response.body().toString());
            }else{
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"oops!!!something went wrong..try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Registration.this, t.getStackTrace().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("###error1" + t.getMessage());
            System.out.println("###stack trace: ");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

I just want to know how do i send image using post object request where i am using @Body in interface...should i use multipart inside my pojo class or how exactly i have to do it .. please help me out

Any Help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your image to bitmap and then string.

```
    String base64String = "";
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bytes);
        image.recycle();
        bytes.close();
        base64String = Base64.encodeToString(bytes.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        OSSUtils.logError(e.getMessage());
    }
```

and then send to your POST method.

Comment: dont i need to send it in multipart encoding ? how exactly i have to do after converting image to bitmap? should i send it in the same way as i am doing above with retrofit @body?

Comment: exactly... you made another attribute of SeekerProfileModel and assign it to it. then send the object... rest of the work should be done by the server.

Comment: means no need of multipart stuffs ?

Comment: I actually did it once with the 12MP camera pic. So I am quite sure about it though I have doubt that there might be limit on size.

Answer (score 0):

interface.java

```
@Multipart
    @POST("file_upload/fileUpload.php")
    Call<ResponsePojo> submitData(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                  @Part("email") String email,
                                  @Part("website") String website);
}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
// this will build full path of API url where we want to send data.

                Retrofit builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(ROOT_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                SubmitAPI api = builder.create(SubmitAPI.class);

                //create file which we want to send to server.
                File imageFIle = new File(String.valueOf(realUri));

                //request body is used to attach file.
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),imageFIle);

                //and request body and file name using multipart.
                MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", imageFIle.getName(),requestBody); //"image" is parameter for photo in API.

                Call<ResponsePojo> call = api.submitData(image, "pawneshwergupta@gmail.com", "learnpainless.com"); //we will get our response in call variable.

                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponsePojo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponsePojo> call, Response<ResponsePojo> response) {
                        ResponsePojo body = response.body(); //get body from response.


                        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        alert.setMessage(body.getMessage()); //display response in Alert dialog.
                        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        alert.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponsePojo> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

For more details https://learnpainless.com/android/retrofit2/send-multiple-files-to-server-using-retrofi2  follow this tutorial.

Comment: i have 23 other fields along with image such as fname,lname,email,address,state,city ..etc etc and a field called profilepic... so i have been serializing pojo model class in interface as like Multipart
 POST("empowerapp/seekerreg.php")
 Call<ResponseModel> registerSeeker(
 Body SeekerProfileModel profileModel);

Comment: it says no retrofit annotation found with following above code .. @user7357013